# UINavigationBar is hiding when activityViewController is presented

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

My project is entire in Storyboard, I have a `UITableViewController` embed in a `NavigationController` and on each cell I have a button to Share the Notice.

```
   @IBAction  func shareSheetButtonFeed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPos)!
        passaValor = Int(indexPath.row)
        let printtestess = (objects?[passaValor] as! PFObject)

        let textToShare: AnyObject = (printtestess.objectForKey("subject")! as! String) + " - Cheque agora em:"


        let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.mysite.com.br/")
        let img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "myLogo-1024x1024")!

        guard let url = myWebsite else {
            print("nothing found")
            return
        }
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        let shareItems:Array = [img, textToShare, url]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)  
        }
```

The problem is, when I click in the button the shareSheet is presented, after I choose the Social Network, like Twitter or Facebook my previous NavigationBar dissapear.

I tried to solve the problem using this line, inside the button, and when I click again in the button the navBar reappear:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

So I tried to put this line inside the `ViewWillAppear`, but it did not work.

Obs: I'm using Auto-Layout

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting until the share sheet is closed to show the navigation bar. To do so, set the `completionWithItemsHandler` property on [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIActivityViewController/completionWithItemsHandler).

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { _ in
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I just need to wait 16 hours to award the bounty.